# Do I need to distribute licenses for Python modules used in code that I release but don't directly distribute (i.e. users pip install modules)?)?

Tags: gpl-3, license-compatibility, license-recommendation, python

I intend to publish the code for my thesis under an appropriate open-source license, such as GPL v3. The code consists of Python and compiled C code that either imports or is statically linked to certain python/other modules. I have not modified any of these external modules. However, I will not distribute any of the code or modules myself, leaving that task to the user during the installation process.

I have three questions:

- Is it necessary to distribute all the licenses separately, or is that requirement satisfied when the user installs the modules themselves?
- Can I release my code under GPL v3?
- Are there any other obligations or advice I should be aware of?

As this is my first question on StackExchange, I hope that I have adhered to the general conventions when posing questions to the community.

| External modules | Version | Licence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cryptography | 3.4.7 | Apache |
| dataclasses | 0.6 | Apache |
| importlib-metadata | 6.1.0 | Apache |
| packaging | 21 | Apache |
| pyOpenSSL | 20.0.1 | Apache |
| python-dateutil | 2.8.1 | Apache |
| python-dateutil | 2.8.2 | Apache |
| python-editor | 1.0.4 | Apache |
| requests | 2.26.0 | Apache |
| tornado | 6.1 | Apache |
| click | 7.1.2 | BSD |
| cloudpickle | 1.6.0 | BSD |
| cycler | 0.10.0 | BSD |
| cytoolz | 0.11.0 | BSD |
| dask | 2021.8.0 | BSD |
| decorator | 4.4.2 | BSD |
| Flask-SQLAlchemy | 2.4.4 | BSD |
| Flask-WTF | 0.14.3 | BSD |
| fsspec | 2021.7.0 | BSD |
| idna | 2.1 | BSD |
| idna | 3.1 | BSD |
| imagecodecs | 2021.7.30 | BSD |
| imageio | 2.8.0 | BSD |
| imageio | 2.9.0 | BSD |
| itsdangerous | 1.1.0 | BSD |
| Jinja2 | 2.11.2 | BSD |
| joblib | 1.0.1 | BSD |
| kiwisolver | 1.3.1 | BSD |
| llvmlite | 0.39.1 | BSD |
| locket | 0.2.0 | BSD |
| MarkupSafe | 1.1.1 | BSD |
| networkx | 2.6.2 | BSD |
| numba | 0.56.4 | BSD |
| numpy | 1.17.3 | BSD |
| numpy | 1.21.2 | BSD |
| olefile | 0.46 | BSD |
| pandas | 1.0.3 | BSD |
| pandas | 1.3.2 | BSD |
| partd | 1.2.0 | BSD |
| pooch | 1.4.0 | BSD |
| PTable | 0.9.2 | BSD |
| pycparser | 2.2 | BSD |
| pyserial | 3.4 | BSD |
| PySocks | 1.7.1 | BSD |
| pywin32-ctypes | 0.2.0 | BSD |
| scikit-image | 0.18.2 | BSD |
| scipy | 1.4.1 | BSD |
| scipy | 1.7.1 | BSD |
| threadpoolctl | 2.2.0 | BSD |
| tifffile | 2021.8.8 | BSD |
| toolz | 0.11.1 | BSD |
| Werkzeug | 1.0.1 | BSD |
| WTForms | 2.3.3 | BSD |
| sklearn | 0 | BSD v3 |
| Arrayfire | v3.7.2 | BSD-3 |
| Flask | 1.1.2 | BSD-3-Clause |
| Flask-Bootstrap | 3.3.7.1 | BSD-3-Clause |
| email-validator | 1.1.1 | CC0 |
| win-inet-pton | 1.1.0 | Custom |
| emailvalidator | 0.3 | Freeware |
| chardet | 4.0.0 | LGPL v2.0 |
| Pillow | 7.1.2 | HPND |
| Pillow | 8.3.1 | HPND |
| dnspython | 2.0.0 | ISC |
| pygame | 1.9.6 | LGPL |
| dominate | 2.5.2 | LGPLv3 |
| alembic | 1.4.3 | MIT |
| altgraph | 0.17 | MIT |
| appdirs | 1.4.4 | MIT |
| brotlipy | 0.7.0 | MIT |
| cffi | 1.14.6 | MIT |
| charset-normalizer | 2.0.0 | MIT |
| Flask-Login | 0.5.0 | MIT |
| Flask-Migrate | 2.5.3 | MIT |
| future | 0.18.2 | MIT |
| imutils | 0.5.4 | MIT |
| Mako | 1.1.3 | MIT |
| nidaqmx | 0.5.7 | MIT |
| opencv-python | 4.2.0.34 | MIT |
| pyparsing | 2.4.7 | MIT |
| pytz | 2019.3 | MIT |
| pytz | 2021.1 | MIT |
| PyWavelets | 1.1.1 | MIT |
| PyYAML | 5.4.1 | MIT |
| RangeSlider | 2021.7.4 | MIT |
| screeninfo | 0.6.5 | MIT |
| six | 1.12.0 | MIT |
| six | 1.16.0 | MIT |
| SQLAlchemy | 1.3.19 | MIT |
| toml | 0.10.2 | MIT |
| urllib3 | 1.26.6 | MIT |
| visitor | 0.1.3 | MIT |
| vulture | 2.7 | MIT |
| xmltodict | 0.12.0 | MIT |
| zipp | 3.15.0 | MIT |
| certifi | 2021.5.30 | Mozilla |
| scikit-learn | 0.24.2 | BSD-3 |
| Anaconda Python |  | Propietory |
| Visual Studio 17 Community Edition | 17 | Proprietary |
| matplotlib | 3.4.3 | BSD/PSF |
| regex | 2019.06.08 | Python |
| wincertstore | 0.2 | Python |
| pefile | 2019.4.18 | MIT |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it necessary to distribute all the licenses separately, or is that requirement satisfied when the user installs the modules themselves?

You must comply with the licenses for all software where your use would otherwise violate copyright. In particular, you must comply with the licenses of all software components that you distribute. If you only publish source code but no binaries or pre-bundled packages, then you only have to consider the components in your source tree. A typical Python module does not contain other components.

So you probably don't have to distribute your dependencies' licenses. But this depends on the source code that you publish – I'm assuming that your source code / repository contains no third party material at all.

> Can I release my code under GPL v3?

Probably yes. You can publish your own source code that is not derived from other people's code under whatever license you want. However, it could be that the resulting software as a whole (consisting of your components and other people's components) would be covered by incompatible licenses, making it impossible to legally distribute pre-built or bundled versions of the software.

Your list of dependencies mostly includes software under GPLv3-compatible licenses (Apache, BSD, Python, MIT, …), but a couple of entries that should be investigated more carefully:

| name | version | license |
| --- | --- | --- |
| win-inet-pton | 1.1.0 | Custom |
| emailvalidator | 0.3 | Freeware |
| Anaconda Python |  | Propietory |
| Visual Studio 17 Community Edition | 17 | Proprietary |

It's also worth noting that package metadata can be incorrect. E.g. win-inet-pton seems to actually have a public domain dedication (no copyright restrictions), and emailvalidator has utterly unclear licensing (but the package provides so little value that you can probably remove it). It is likely that the licensing of Anaconda and Visual Studio is quite irrelevant for you since they do not typically become part of the software.

Even if there were incompatible licenses, you would be able to issue a GPL exception under section 7 of the GPL-3.0. This works here because there are no other AGPL/GPL-covered dependencies.

> Are there any other obligations or advice I should be aware of?

Publishing your own source code is fairly straightforward to do, even if running that source code would depend on other people's software. Licensing gets more tricky when you're creating derivative works from other people's software (for example, by modifying their software, by copying their code into your project, or by distributing binaries or packages that include their components), or when dealing with components with non-Open Source licenses, since their licenses/EULAs might have unusual usage restrictions.

Comment: Thank you! I found your answer informed and clear.  I would upvote if I could.